# must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

Swift初学者です。
チュートリアルを参考にSNSアプリ制作中です。
シミュレーターを起動し、SettingViewControllerからEditProfileViewControllerへ遷移しようとするとシミュレーターが落ち、以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
5 ->  0x7fff5dca633a <+10>: jae  0x7fff5dca6344  ; <+20>  Thread 1: "must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell"
```

正直自力では対処できず、こちらに投稿させていただきました。助言いただければ幸いです。

以下はコンソールに表示されたメッセージです。

```
2020-10-09 21:01:28.976434+0900 gyosufan[1250:35937] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.3.1
2020-10-09 21:01:29.174470+0900 gyosufan[1250:37408] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-10-09 21:01:29.270831+0900 gyosufan[1250:37408] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60602000 started
2020-10-09 21:01:29.321321+0900 gyosufan[1250:37408] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo.gl/RfcP7r)
2020-10-09 21:01:29.365774+0900 gyosufan[1250:37408] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-09 21:01:29.616851+0900 gyosufan[1250:37403] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-10-09 21:01:30.616189+0900 gyosufan[1250:37403] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-10-09 21:01:33.545505+0900 gyosufan[1250:37407] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2020-10-09 21:01:34.164445+0900 gyosufan[1250:37429] 6.28.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Failed to download settings Error Domain=FIRCLSNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=404, type=2, request_id=, content_type=text/html; charset=utf-8}
2020-10-09 21:01:41.382143+0900 gyosufan[1250:35937] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a004 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2488193e -[UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:] + 316
    4   gyosufan                            0x000000010749c7fa $s8gyosufan25EditProfileViewControllerC05tableD033_2A81A928A072FB25008A8B68CBA5016BLLSo07UITableD0CvpfiAGyXEfU_ + 138
    5   gyosufan                            0x000000010749feda $s8gyosufan25EditProfileViewControllerC7nibName6bundleACSSSg_So8NSBundleCSgtcfc + 186
    6   gyosufan                            0x00000001074a013c $s8gyosufan25EditProfileViewControllerC7nibName6bundleACSSSg_So8NSBundleCSgtcfcTo + 172
    7   gyosufan                            0x00000001074a1633 $sSo16UIViewControllerCABycfcTO + 19
    8   gyosufan                            0x00000001074a160f $sSo16UIViewControllerCABycfC + 31
    9   gyosufan                            0x00000001074bb26c $s8gyosufan21SettingViewControllerC17didTapEditProfile33_2BE0CAC7A25DB4FEB40CD0146FEA96B1LLyyF + 76
    10  gyosufan                            0x00000001074bb206 $s8gyosufan21SettingViewControllerC15configureModels33_2BE0CAC7A25DB4FEB40CD0146FEA96B1LLyyFyycfU_ + 198
    11  gyosufan                            0x00000001074bdae5 $s8gyosufan21SettingViewControllerC05tableC0_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableC0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 725
    12  gyosufan                            0x00000001074bdbb7 $s8gyosufan21SettingViewControllerC05tableC0_14didSelectRowAtySo07UITableC0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 167
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff248787f6 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:isCellMultiSelect:] + 1081
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff248783a6 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 97
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24878cf5 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 334
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24b5697a -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 54
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2466f85d _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 333
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2465f790 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 221
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24691154 _afterCACommitHandler + 85
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a76b3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a1f3f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 547
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a24e2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1113
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a1b9e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2b773db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24660af3 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24665a04 UIApplicationMain + 101
    27  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff539f37b2 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
    28  gyosufan                            0x00000001074ab76a $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
    29  gyosufan                            0x00000001074ab6de $s8gyosufan11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
    30  gyosufan                            0x00000001074ab7b9 main + 41
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20257415 start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.17 - Device: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (52F44A5A-DA3B-4922-8049-5BE63803AA59) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A372) - DeviceType: iPhone SE (2nd generation)
(lldb)
```

解決に至らなかったためコメントいただいた通り、追加させていただきます。

```
import SafariServices
import UIKit

struct SettingCellModel {
    let title: String
    let handler: (() -> Void)
}

//ユーザー設定
final class SettingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero,
                                    style: .grouped)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()
    
    private var data = [[SettingCellModel]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureModels()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    private func configureModels() {
        data.append([
            SettingCellModel(title: "プロフィールを編集") { [weak self] in
                self?.didTapEditProfile()
            },
            SettingCellModel(title: "友達を招待") { [weak self] in
                self?.didTapInviteFriends()
            },
            SettingCellModel(title: "投稿を保存") { [weak self] in
                self?.didTapSaveOriginalPosts()
            }
        ])
        
        data.append([
        SettingCellModel(title: "利用規約") { [weak self] in
            self?.openURL(type: .terms)
        },
        SettingCellModel(title: "プライバシーポリシー") { [weak self] in
            self?.openURL(type: .privacy)
        },
        SettingCellModel(title: "ヘルプ") { [weak self] in
            self?.openURL(type: .help)
        }
    ])
        
        data.append([
            SettingCellModel(title: "ログアウト") { [weak self] in
                self?.didTapLogOut()
            }
        ])
    }
    
    enum SettingsURLType {
        case terms, privacy, help
    }
    
    private func openURL(type: SettingsURLType) {
        let urlString: String
        switch type {
        case .terms: urlString = "https://help.instagram.com/581066165581870"
        case .privacy: urlString = "https://help.instagram.com/519522125107875"
        case .help: urlString = "https://help.instagram.com/"
        }
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func didTapSaveOriginalPosts() {
        
    }
    
    private func didTapInviteFriends() {
        //友達を招待する
        
    }
    
    private func didTapEditProfile() {
        let vc = EditProfileViewController()
        vc.title = "プロフィールを編集"
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        present(navVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func didTapLogOut() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "ログアウト",
                                            message: "ログアウトしますか？",
                                            preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "キャンセル",
                                            style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ログアウト",
                                            style: .destructive, handler: { _ in
                                                AuthManager.shared.logOut(completion: { success in
                                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                        if success {
                                                            //ログイン中
                                                            let loginVC = LoginViewController()
                                                            loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                                                            self.present(loginVC, animated: true) {
                                                                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                                                                self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                            //エラー発生
                                                            fatalError("ログアウト失敗")
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                })
                                            }))
        
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = tableView
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = tableView.bounds
        
        present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }
}

extension SettingViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].handler()
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

struct EditProfileForModel {
    let label: String
    let placeholder: String
    var value: String?
    
}

final class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.register(UITableView.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()
    
    private var models = [[EditProfileForModel]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureModels()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = createTableHeaderView()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "保存",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(didTapSave)
        )
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "キャンセル",
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(didTapCancel)
        )
    }
    
    private func configureModels() {
        //名前、ユーザー名、サイト、経歴
        let section1Labels = ["名前","ユーザー名","経歴"]
        var section1 = [EditProfileForModel]()
        for label in section1Labels {
            let model = EditProfileForModel(label: label,
                                            placeholder: "決定 \(label)",
                                            value: nil)
            section1.append(model)
        }
        models.append(section1)
        //アドレス、電話番号、性別
        let section2Labels = ["メールアドレス","電話番号","性別"]
        var section2 = [EditProfileForModel]()
        for label in section2Labels {
            let model = EditProfileForModel(label: label,
                                            placeholder: "決定 \(label)",
                                            value: nil)
            section2.append(model)
        }
        models.append(section2)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    //mark tableview
    
    private func createTableHeaderView() -> UIView {
        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                          y: 0,
                                          width: view.width,
                                          height: view.height/4).integral)
        let size = header.height/1.5
        let profilePhotoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (view.width-size)/2,
                                                        y: (header.height-size)/2,
                                                        width: size,
                                                        height: size))
        header.addSubview(profilePhotoButton)
        profilePhotoButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        profilePhotoButton.layer.cornerRadius = size/2.0
        profilePhotoButton.tintColor = .label
        profilePhotoButton.addTarget(self,
                                     action: #selector(didTapProfilePhotoButton),
                                     for: .touchUpInside)
        
        profilePhotoButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.circle"),
                                              for: .normal)
        profilePhotoButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        profilePhotoButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground.cgColor
        
        return header
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapProfilePhotoButton() {
        
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let model = models[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = model.label
        return cell
    }
    
    //mark action
    
    @objc private func didTapSave() {
        //データベースに情報を保存
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapCancel() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapChangeProfilePicture() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(
            title: "プロフィール写真",
            message: "プロフィール写真を変更",
            preferredStyle: .actionSheet
        )
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(
                                title: "カメラで撮影",
                                style: .default,
                                handler: { _ in})
        )
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(
                                title: "ライブラリーから選択",
                                style: .default,
                                handler: { _ in})
        )
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(
                                title: "キャンセル",
                                style: .cancel,
                                handler: nil))
        
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.bounds
        
        present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: 例外発生時のスタックに`[UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:]`とあり、理由が`must pass a class of kind UITableViewCell`とあるのですから、`register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`で変なクラスを渡しているんだろうとしか言えません。それでご自身で解決できない場合には、どの行で例外が発生しているのかを突き止めて、その行を含むメソッドと関連する部分全てのソースコードを本文中に追記してください。

Comment: `EditProfileViewController`の中で、`private let tableView`の中身で、`tableView.register(UITableView.self, ...)`とあるのは、`tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, ...)`の間違いではありませんか?

Comment: おっしゃる通りでエラーは無くなりました！基本的なことが理解できていないと言うことですね。。ありがとうございました！

Comment: エラーメッセージやスタックトレースの隅々まで見ていくのは大変なんで、慣れの部分も大きいと思います。このサイトでは「コメント」は「回答」とは全くの別という扱いなので、少し時間をとって修正内容を自己回答として書き込むようにお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tableView.register(UITableView.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

上記から下記に修正したことで改善できました。

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```